# Fitch proof (constructing formal proofs)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Good official afternoon community,

I am trying to construct a formal proof for the following argument: 
(P → (Q → R)) ↔ ((P ∧ Q) → R)

I have no idea how to start. This is the outline I put for myself to follow (one of my trials). [image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good set-up at all.  Since you need to prove a biconditional, look at the rule of $\leftrightarrow$ Intro, and you'll see that you need two subproofs: one going from left to right, and the other one going from right to left.

Here's a trick:

Focus on the desired line and choose the rule through which you intend to derive that line, which is of course $\leftrightarrow$ Intro. Then go to the Proof Menu and select 'Add Support Steps':

[image]

Magic will happen! :)

Comment: ok, I will try that now

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyKg9.png

Comment: I do not know if this is right or wrong now. I will try to finish the proof although I keep missing it up but I will see. Thank you

Comment: it is not working, :(

Comment: @markjohn Hey, what you had in the image was all good so far!  You're getting close in fact.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nStjL.png..  Ok, so I went back to the link you told me to search for the last time "system for Logic Proofs'" and read it again. I did finish the proof using the explanation you provided in that link but I do not know if it is correct. I watched a video on how to use the "add support steps" and that is truly magic. That's helps a lot. It saved me at least 3 minutes if not more, which is amazing. This is my last trial. i.stack.imgur.com/nStjL.png Thank you

Comment: @markjohn that's it, you got it!  Good work!

Comment: Thank you professor, I appreciate your time

Comment: @markjohn You're welcome! Glad I can help!

Answer (score 1):

$\vdash (p\to (q\to r)\leftrightarrow ((p\wedge q)\to r)$

For each conditional subproof for this biconditional proof, first assume the antecendant, and further assume what you need to set up for the final conditional introduction.   The argument between should suggest itself.

$\begin{array}{r|ll}
1. &\quad p\to (q\to r) & \text{Assume}
\\ 2. & \qquad p\wedge q & \text{Assume}
\\ 3. & \qquad \vdots\phantom{p} & \vdots\phantom{2, \text{Conjunction Elimination}}
\\ 4. & \qquad \vdots\phantom{q\to r} & \vdots\phantom{1,3,\text{Conditional Elimination}}
\\ 5. & \qquad \vdots\phantom{q} & \vdots\phantom{2,\text{Conjunction Elimination}}
\\ 6. & \qquad r & \vdots\phantom{4,5,\text{Conditional Elimination}}
\\ 7. & \quad (p\wedge q)\to r & 2,6,\text{Conditional Introduction}
\\ 8. & (p\to(q\to r))\to ((p\wedge q)\to r) & 1,7,\text{Conditional Introduction}
\\[2ex] 7. & \quad (p\wedge q)\to r & \text{Assume}
\\ 8. & \qquad p & \text{Assume}
\\ 9. & \qquad\quad q &\text{Assume}
\\ 10. & \qquad\quad \vdots\phantom{p\wedge q} & \vdots\phantom{9,10,\text{Conjunction Introduction}}
\\ 11. & \qquad\quad r & \vdots\phantom{7,10, \text{Conditional Elimination}}
\\ 12. & \qquad q\to r & 9,11,\text{Conditional Introduction}
\\ 13. & \quad p\to(q\to r) & 8,12,\text{Conditional Introduction}
\\ 14. & ((p\wedge q)\to r)\to(p\to(q\to r)) & 7,13,\text{Conditional Introduction}
\\[2ex] 15. & (p\to(q\to r))\mathop{\leftrightarrow} ((p\wedge q)\to r) & 8,14,\text{Biconditional Introduction}
\end{array}$